# Making a button invisible (not hidden)

Tags: jquery, html, css, button

How can I make a button to be invisible so that users can not see the button but can press it.

I have been trying to do this, but all the results I have found lead to hidden button.

Comment: I need that button because I have an iamge, on that image there is a place for placing a button. So I want to place an invisible onto that place.

Comment: You could have just an OnClick even on the image, with a form Submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried changing the background color, borders and color, to the same a the bakground color of the page?

```
body{
   color: white;
}

.button {
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0px none transparent;
}
```

There are however many other ways to achieve this, depending on why you need to do it.

or the following:

```
.transparent {
    zoom: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
}
```

as noted on the CSS tricks link, for reference purposes here.

Comment: Dear ShaunOreilly: As I commented above, there is no need to use background color :). About transparent, could you please give me some advises ?

Comment: Gotcha, "opacity: 0;" 

Thank you, guys. :)

Comment: Ensure you add the IE7 specific bits

Answer (score 2):

Why don't go with `<input type="image">` then?

Answer (score 1):

CSS has `opacity: 0` to allow no visibility but full functionality:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#button { opacity: 0;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function go()
{
    alert('clicked');
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="button" onclick="go()">hello</button></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tell that to the IE7 users not the web developers :)

Answer (score 0):

filter: alpha(opacity=0);
opacity: 0;

there are some more styling options targeting even older browsers @ http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/

Answer (score 0):

```
`.button1 {
 margin: 10px 0px 0px 4px;
 position: absolute; 
 filter: alpha(opacity=65);
 -mos-opacity: 0.65;
 opacity: 0.65; 
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 85px;
 width: 85px;
 }`
```